# I guess, pull-up/down resistors fried. What can i do?

Tags: arduino-mega

Arduino Mega ADK is working well but it is not working circuit in which pull-up/down resistors. It is generating wrong results. I guess, pull-up/down resistors fried. What can i do?

Comment: Replace them...?

Comment: @Majenko i didnt get

Comment: You and me both. I don't have a clue what you're asking. Your question needs to be about 100 times the length it is. Just asking "I don't think *X* works, what do I do" will not get you an answer - least ways not one you can make any sense of.  You need to describe what you have done, describe the results you expect, and most importantly *describe the results you are actually getting*. Schematics, pictures, code - all of it.

Comment: This site is not like your typical forum structure where you discuss the problem in a thread. You get one place to ask your question, and that question is all you get. It has to contain *everything* we need to be able to work out what is wrong.

Comment: @Majenko i know this site's principle. i want to say that i dont understand your comment and typed "didnt get it". you didn't need to wax eloquent.

Comment: Well, I see no attempt by you to ask a reasonably understandable question, so I figured you needed some help to understand what you needed to do in order to get the help with your project you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want internal pullup or pulldown resistors on input pins, you can use external ones to do the same job as internal ones if you wish to. Generally, if you use say 100 k Ohms from a pin to V+ or ground then it will act as a pullup or pull down respectively on an input pin, but have much effect on an output pin - which is what you want to happen.

However, it is unlikely that 'fried internal resistors is the reason for code not working and, if this is the case, there is probably unknown and unknowable other damage as well. Pull up/down resistors are usually not actually resistors. They are FETs with high Rds_on values that look resistor like when on. Anything that "fries" them has a reasonable prospect of doing other damage as well.